# Sonarqube incorrectly reports “Unexpected missing generic font family “Roboto” and “Poppins”” in React Native

Tags: react-native, sass, sonarqube, font-family

I read rule description for generic font family it's indicates to write like.

It’s recommended to always define a generic font family for each declaration of font or font-family to get a less degraded situation than relying on the default browser font. All browsers should implement a list of generic font matching these families: Serif, Sans-serif, cursive, fantasy, Monospace.

Here is my Code in react native, it’s not accepting “font-family: ‘Poppins’,sans-serif ;” this syntax of code throwing error in sass styles.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

.container {
  flex: 1;
}
.labelBlack {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-family: 'Poppins',sans-serif ;
  color: $lightblack;
  align-self: center

}
```

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIE0C.png)